# how to detect select option change by jquery

Tags: jquery

```js
$("#btnReset").on("click", function() {
  $("#ddl1")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
  $("#ddl2")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
});

$('#ddl1').on('change', function() {
     alert('detect on clear');
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddl1" style="width: 150px;">
  <option value="0">Please select1</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="ddl2">
  <option value="0">Please select2</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" />
```

Examples. I have **clearFilter** Button. When I click **clearFilter** button.All select box are reset to option 0. All select are with on change events. But on click **clearFitler** button click not work on change event.

[image]

```
$('#ddl1').on('change', function() {
     alert('detect on reset button change to select button');
   });
```

Comment: Use .trigger to trigger the onChange event handler: ```$(".filter").trigger("change")```

Comment: There is an [onReset event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onreset)

Comment: share your code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `selectedIndex` to reset your dropdown like below.

```js
$("#btnReset").on("click", function() {
  if ($("#ddl1")[0].selectedIndex != 0) {
    $('#ddl1').trigger('change');
    $("#ddl1")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
  }
  if ($("#ddl2")[0].selectedIndex != 0) {
    $('#ddl2').trigger('change');
    $("#ddl2")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
  }
});
$('#ddl1').on('change', function() {
  alert('detect on reset button change to select button');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="ddl1" style="width: 150px;">
  <option value="0">Please select1</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
</select>
<select id="ddl2">
  <option value="0">Please select2</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
  <option value="5">5</option>
  <option value="6">6</option>
  <option value="7">7</option>
</select>

<input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `val` with `""` and put an option with `value=""`

```js
$('#resetBtn').on('click', function() {
  $('#sel1').val("");
  $('#sel2').val("");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="sel1">
  <option value="">-- Select Opt 1 --</option>
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
</select>

<select id="sel2">
  <option value="">-- Select Opt 2 --</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>

<button id="resetBtn">Reset Filter</button>
```